# How to create periods in dataFrame using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create periods with using cumsum() and cumcount(). How to create periods for each book?

Period - continuous weekly sequence. 
For example If (week) - (previous week) > 1 => new period.

I've tried

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'book_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2],
                   'week_id': [199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 208, 209,211, 212, 213,214,216,217,218,219,220,222,223,224,225,226,228]})

df['discount_weeks']=df.groupby(['book_id', df['week_id'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()]).cumcount()+1

df['discount_periods'] = df.groupby(['book_id','discount_weeks']).cumcount()+1

df['total'] = df['discount_weeks'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
print(df)


    book_id  week_id  discount_weeks  discount_periods  total
0         1      199               1                 1      1
1         1      200               2                 1      1
2         1      201               3                 1      1
3         1      202               4                 1      1
4         1      203               5                 1      1
5         1      204               6                 1      1
6         1      205               7                 1      1
7         1      206               8                 1      1
8         1      208               1                 2      2
9         1      209               2                 2      2
10        1      211               1                 3      3
11        1      212               2                 3      3
12        1      213               3                 2      3
13        1      214               4                 2      3
14        1      216               1                 4      4
15        1      217               2                 4      4
16        1      218               3                 3      4
17        1      219               4                 3      4
18        1      220               5                 2      4
19        1      222               1                 5      5
20        1      223               2                 5      5
21        1      224               3                 4      5
22        2      225               1                 1      6
23        2      226               2                 1      6
24        2      228               1                 2      7
```

but 'discount_periods' works incorrectly in some places (12,13,16,17,18 ...)

Final result should be:

```py
    book_id  week_id  discount_weeks  discount_periods  total
0         1      199               1                 1      1
1         1      200               2                 1      1
2         1      201               3                 1      1
3         1      202               4                 1      1
4         1      203               5                 1      1
5         1      204               6                 1      1
6         1      205               7                 1      1
7         1      206               8                 1      1
8         1      208               1                 2      2
9         1      209               2                 2      2
10        1      211               1                 3      3
11        1      212               2                 3      3
12        1      213               3                 3      3
13        1      214               4                 3      3
14        1      216               1                 4      4
15        1      217               2                 4      4
16        1      218               3                 4      4
17        1      219               4                 4      4
18        1      220               5                 4      4
19        1      222               1                 5      5
20        1      223               2                 5      5
21        1      224               3                 5      5
22        2      225               1                 1      6
23        2      226               2                 1      6
24        2      228               1                 2      7
```

Maybe other methods will work better here than cumsum(), cumcount()?

Comment: In what way is your solution not working? It looks like `discount_periods` correctly labels each run of consecutive `week_id`s with a unique integer for each `book_id` group, which looks like the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a new column, `start_period`:

```
df['start_period'] = (df['discount_weeks'].diff().ne(1)).astype(int)
```

Then, for each `book_id`, you can define `discount_periods` as the cumulative sum of `start_period`:

```
df['discount_periods'] = df.groupby(['book_id'])['start_period'].cumsum()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'book_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2],
    'week_id': [199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 208, 209,211, 212, 213,214,216,
                217,218,219,220,222,223,224,225,226,228]})

df['discount_weeks']=df.groupby(['book_id', df['week_id'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()]).cumcount()+1
df['total'] = df['discount_weeks'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()

# df['start_period'] = (df['discount_weeks'] == 1).astype(int)  # also works, if every period starts with discount_weeks equal to 1
df['start_period'] = (df['discount_weeks'].diff().ne(1)).astype(int)
df['discount_periods'] = df.groupby(['book_id'])['start_period'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

yields

```
    book_id  week_id  discount_weeks  discount_periods  total  
0         1      199               1                 1      1  
1         1      200               2                 1      1  
2         1      201               3                 1      1  
3         1      202               4                 1      1  
4         1      203               5                 1      1  
5         1      204               6                 1      1  
6         1      205               7                 1      1  
7         1      206               8                 1      1  
8         1      208               1                 2      2  
9         1      209               2                 2      2  
10        1      211               1                 3      3  
11        1      212               2                 3      3  
12        1      213               3                 3      3  
13        1      214               4                 3      3  
14        1      216               1                 4      4  
15        1      217               2                 4      4  
16        1      218               3                 4      4  
17        1      219               4                 4      4  
18        1      220               5                 4      4  
19        1      222               1                 5      5  
20        1      223               2                 5      5  
21        1      224               3                 5      5  
22        2      225               1                 1      6  
23        2      226               2                 1      6  
24        2      228               1                 2      7
```

Comment: Please edit your post above to include the new data and the desired output *as text*.

Comment: Please label the columns. It's not clear in the image which column represents `book_id`, `discount_weeks`, etc.

Comment: Answer has been changed to address the new dataset.